# CsvHelper ReaderException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]'

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I first tried to read a file with a record which contains a column with the value "120,000.00". I want to convert this column to a nullable decimal.
Although the file originates from Switzerland, C# seems not to be okay with this format and the helper (using the de-CH CultureInfo) raised a TypeConverterException. So I removed the comma with a custom TypeConverter which solved the conversion problem.
Unfortunately, I now get a ReaderException:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]'

Why is still an exception raised after the type conversion has succeeded? Can the behaviour be reproduced?
(CsvHelper version 15.0.8, Stack trace at CsvHelper.CsvReader.d__63`1.MoveNext())

```
public class MyFile
{
    public decimal? MyField { get; set; }
}
```

_

```
public MyFileMap : ClassMap<MyFile>
{
    public MyFileMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.MyField).Name("My Field").TypeConverterOption.NumberStyles(System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number).TypeConverter<DecimalStringReplacer>();  //custom replacer removes the comma
    }
}
```

_

```
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<MyFile>() //csvReader uses CultureInfo "de-CH". Raises ReaderException
```

Comment: You can just assume here is no culture in a SV. and use : CultureInfo.InvariantCulture . `Console.WriteLine(132456789.ToString("n", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` -> `132,456,789.00`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not implement the custom converter correctly. This needs to return a nullable decimal, while my implementation (which I had just copy-pasted) returned a string.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `NumberGroupSeparator` for de-CH is `’` and not `,`.

This will work fine:

```
using var reader = new StringReader(
            """
            "120’000.00"
            """);
using var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-CH"));
if (csvReader.Read())
{
    var result = csvReader.GetField<decimal>(0);
}
```

Try to switch to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which seems to fit your formatting.

Comment: I though I've seen all weird separators already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, U+066C is a fun one too. it look like a comma.

Comment: @Magnus I understand. If I remove the NumberGroupSeparator with the help of the custom TypeConverter, still a ReaderException is thrown. Why does that happen?

Comment: Dont remove it. Just use the correct culture.